# Object not iterable when assigning to a list

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am coding a 2048 game via pygame. below is the relevant section of my code:

```
class Data():
    def __init__(self):
            self.data = getnull()
            self.score = 0
    def updatesprites(self):            # EXP
            spritelist = [[],[],[],[]]
            for count in range(4): # for row loop
                for i in range(4): # per column loop
                    if self.data[count][i] != 0:
                        spritelist[count]+= newSprite(str(self.data[count] [i])+".png")   # error occurs here
                        spritelist[count][i].move(15 + i*115, 15 + count*115)
                        showSprite(spritelist[count][i])
class newSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images=[]
        self.images.append(loadImage(filename))
        self.image = pygame.Surface.copy(self.images[0])
        self.currentImage = 0
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft=(0,0)
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.angle = 0

    def addImage(self, filename):
        self.images.append(loadImage(filename))

    def move(self,xpos,ypos,centre=False):
        if centre:
            self.rect.center = [xpos,ypos]
        else:
            self.rect.topleft = [xpos,ypos]
```

## ----------------Main-------------------

```
from functions import *
from config import *
from pygame_functions import *
import pygame
screenSize(475,475) # call screen init
gameboard = newSprite("game board.png") # createboard
showSprite(gameboard)
game = Data()
game.updatesprites()   

while True:
    pass
```

when game.updatesprites() is called, "newSprite object is not iterable" error is raised in function Data.updatesprites

Comment: Please consider looking into PEP008 (the python style guide)

Comment: always add full error message (Traceback). We can't run code and see it but there are many usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

`+` concatenates lists and strings, and adds numbers.

What you are trying to do, is to add an element to a list.

This is done as follows:

```py
li.append(element)  # adds the element to the end of the list
```

Or in your case:

```
spritelist[count].append(newSprite(str(self.data[count][i]) + ".png"))
```

Another solution: You could create a new type, that lets you add elements the way you were trying to:

```
class UglyList(list):
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.append(other)
```

You'd need to change another line here:

```
spritelist = [UglyList() for i in range(4)]
```